# PayPal IPN, how to get chosen price from dropdown menu

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

PayPal button can have drop down menu, like:

- Option 1 - $5
- Option 2 - $10
- Option 3 - $15

When I'm processing payment by IDN, how will I get which option user chosen? I'm not sure if I can do it  only based on paid price, since tax/fees/currency could change. Does PayPal somehow pass chosen value?

*{"address_city":"San Jose","address_country":"United States","address_country_code":"US","address_name":"John Smith","address_state":"CA","address_status":"confirmed","address_street":"123 any street","address_zip":"95131","business":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","custom":"xyz123","first_name":"John","invoice":"abc1234","item_name":"something","item_number":"AK-1234","last_name":"Smith","mc_currency":"USD","mc_fee":"0.44","mc_gross":"12.34","mc_gross_1":"9.34","notify_version":"2.1","payer_email":"buyer@paypalsandbox.com","payer_id":"TESTBUYERID01","payer_status":"verified","payment_date":"13:07:48 Feb 11, 2020 PST","payment_status":"Pending","payment_type":"instant","quantity":"1","receiver_email":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","receiver_id":"seller@paypalsandbox.com","residence_country":"US","shipping":"3.04","tax":"2.02","test_ipn":"1","txn_id":"561648507","txn_type":"web_accept","verify_sign":"AzMNkTxgBvm9UMEVF6xwI2k3UvAsAl6Uv1oAXhmEDejTPin9MM39F2Td"}*

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does. Why don't you create an actual sandbox button with a dropdown menu at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&button_type=buynow and test with it, so you can look at the IPN of an actual such button?

You will need to log in to a sandbox business account at www.sandbox.paypal.com first , if you want the IPN to be sent to the one in that account's profile URL. Alternatively, in the button's advanced variable's you can set `notify_url=` to your IPN listener.